# Trying to display image or any type of data dynamically in my ejs template to get from mongodb collections

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I'm learner & trying express & mongodb with ejs in first time. How to show an uploaded image front end by ejs i don't understand. Kindly review following code, mention where is my mistake & based on mistake provide instruction.

Router handle code:

**addmembersroute.js**

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const multer = require('multer');

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: (req, file, callback) => {
        callback(null, './views/uploads/')
      },
      filename: (req, file, callback) => {
        callback(null, file.fieldname + '_' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
      }
    })
const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

const { createMembers } = require('../../middlewares/members/addnewmembercontroller');
router.get('/', createMembers[0]);
router.post('/', upload.single('member_img'), createMembers[1]);
```

createMembers controller handle post request from outside of the route.

createMembers controller code:

**addnewmembercontroller.js**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const MembersModel = require('../../models/Members');
        
exports.createMembers = [(req,res,next) => {
  res.render('../views/pages/members/addmembers');
     next()
 },
   (req,res) => { 
       let {
           member_name, member_mob, member_email ...
       } = req.body;

       let img = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
       let encode_image = img.toString('base64');

       if (req.body && req.file) {    
         const Members = new MembersModel({
            name: member_name, 
            images: {
                  data: Buffer.from(encode_image, 'base64'),
                  contentType: req.file.mimetype
                 },
            .
            .
         })

          Members.save()
                 .then( () => {
                        res.render('../views/pages/members/addmembers')
                     })
                 .catch(error => {
                       res.json({
                           message: `error occured: ${error}`
                     })
                   })
                 }
}]
```

Handle get request from different controller.

**memberscontroller.js**

```
const MembersModel = require('../../models/Members');
exports.getAllMembers = (req,res) => {
  MembersModel.find()
              .then(members => {
                console.log(members);
                res.render('../views/pages/members/allmembers', {members})
              })
              .catch(error => {
                res.render('../views/pages/members/allmembers', {Error: `Error Occured: ${error}`})
              })
}

exports.updateMembersProfile = (req,res) => {
  res.send("I'm update member Profile page")
}

exports.deleteMembersProfile = (req,res) => {
  res.send("I'm delete member Profile page")
}
```

DB collections model:

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose');

const MemberSchema = Schema({
  name: String,
  contact_no: String,
  email: String,
  ...
  images: {
    data: Buffer,
    contentType: String
  }
})

const MembersModel = model('Member', MemberSchema);

module.exports = MembersModel;
```

ejs template for data taking form:

```
<form action="/add-new" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="member-data-form" class="px-lg-3 px-md-3 py-3">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col mb-2 mb-lg-1 mb-md-1">
       <label for="member_name" class="form-label">Full name</label>
       <input type="text" name="member_name" id="member_name" class="form-control" 
       placeholder="exm:John Doe" aria-label="member_name">
     </div>
     <div class="col">
        <div>
           <label for="member_img" class="form-label">(Attach your sharp photo)</label>
        </div>
           <input type="file" name="member_img" id="member_img">
      </div>
   </div>
....
</form>
```

I am able to save user's data in collection & save the file into the upload directory. But when i want to show data on the front end, I can't.

here image render structure:

```
<img src="member_img/<%= memberdata.images.data %> " style="width: 80px; height: auto;" class="img-fluid float-end me-2" alt="member-img">
```

may be I'm doing wrong to structure the image of the template.

Answer (score 0):

`memberdata.images` is a Buffer, which you can convert to a base64 `data:` URL:

```html
<img src="data:<%=
  memberdata.images.contentType
%>,base64;<%=
  memberdata.images.toString("base64")
%>" ...>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it returns me an error. like: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: _____ The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined. If you noticed that i already assign `images: { data: Buffer.from(encode_image, 'base64'), contentType: req.file.mimetype }` in my addnewmembercontroller.js. My mongodb collection provide me bindata as a images data.

Comment: Please share your `allmembers.ejs` template.

Comment: Github repo: (github) (https://github.com/SoummoSinghoRoy/clubmember-list/blob/410a5c636aaba01e14aec6c7989f373e324628cc/views/pages/members/allmembers.ejs) you can check all necessary file & code.

Comment: Can you log `memberdata.images` and post the result here?

Comment: When i logged it's return a binary data in console. But if i wrote `<img src="<%= memberdata.images%>"`. it return as like when the `src` attribute doesn't get the image then the front end shows the alternate name as shown.

Comment: What does `console.log(memberdata.images.contentType)` show?

Comment: it shows `contentType: "image/png"` when i'm testing form, mongodb db collection takes all data & uploaded image. uploaded image take as a bindata/binary data. I don’t understood, how to deal with bindata & convert it for retrieve image. have you need to see db collection document?

Comment: Try my edited answer.

Comment: I inject your 3rd edited context <img src="data:<%= memberdata.images.contentType %>,base64;<%= Buffer.from(memberdata.images).toString("base64") %>"...> & got **TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: ___ The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received an instance of Document.**

Comment: What does `console.log(memberdata.images.toJSON())` show?

Comment: The single document (including image data) in the collection that the user has filled up. I shared log screenshot from my github. (github)(https://github.com/SoummoSinghoRoy/clubmember-list/blob/c6cfe98924e293a3851e03d3e9f32d481cd06313/log.JPG)

Comment: When I try this, `memberdata.images.data` is a buffer, it is not undefined. I have edited my answer again.

Comment: I already tried `<img src="data:<%= memberdata.images.contentType %>,base64;<%= memberdata.images.data.toString("base64") %>"` & got **TypeError: E:\Learn-JS-React\clubmember-list\views\pages\members\allmembers.ejs:44** Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')` you can check (github) (https://github.com/SoummoSinghoRoy/clubmember-list/blob/c6cfe98924e293a3851e03d3e9f32d481cd06313/log.JPG)

Comment: Can there be members who don't have an image perhaps?

Comment: no no! already uploaded image in upload folder & save db. If you feel doubt kindly check or download github repo.

Comment: Did you found any solution? I logged in console type of `memberdata.images.data` it return an object. Then i try to convert object to base64 & define this in src. Again got **TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: ___ The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received an instance of Document.**

Comment: At the beginning you said `memberdata.images.data` gives you "Received undefined". Now you say it gives you "Received an instance of Document".

Comment: Received undefined got when i changed context. But when i check `typeof(memberdata.images.data)` it returns in console object. So i try to convert object to base64 & pass converted variable in `<img src ` than i got that result.